# Get everything after the period in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, substring

I am trying to remove everything before the period in other words i only want to show the values that starts from the period.  For instance

```
897.78 ==> 78 
74.25 ==> 25 
3657.256 ==> 256
```

well the code below only shows everything before the period but i want to show everything after the period

```
select volume, substring(volume from 1 for position('.' in volume) - 1) as column 
from MyTable    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select volume, substring(volume from (position('.' in volume)+1) for length(volume)) as column from MyTable;
```

This should work (not tested since I don't have postgre installed on this pc) :)

EDIT:
even just

```
select volume, substring(volume from position('.' in volume)+1) as column from MyTable;
```

should work since you can define only starting position in substring

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is to use the regex form of [`substring()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html):

```
select volume, substring(volume from '[^.]*$') as column
from
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/35d9b/1) of this query working.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `string_to_array`:

```
select volume,(string_to_array(volume,'.'))[2] as column
from mytable
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/35d9b/3)